# Some doubts about how the loop work (trying debugging it)

Tags: posts, loop, query

I am very new in WordPress development (and also in PHP development, I came from Java and C#). Today I have installed Aptana and configured *XDebug* to inspect what happens into the **TwentyTwelve** theme.

In particular, I am trying to understand how WordPress load the posts in the loop (debbuging it).

So, up until now, I only know how create a loop in a WP theme, but I don't know how exactly it work.

So, in the *TwentyTwelve* I find the post loop, this code snippet:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

From what I can understand the loop is composed by a `while()` cycle where the `have_posts()` result is the condition to execute the while body.

Ok, now probabily the following question is related to my ignorance in PHP, but what exactly does this construction means:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

`have_posts()` is the condition to execute in the while but what exactly means the `: the_post();`

Is `the_post()` call the first operation of the cycle or what?

Then I have put a breakpoint into the `have_posts()` function definied into the *query.php* file.

```
function have_posts() {
    global $wp_query;

    return $wp_query->have_posts();
}
```

What exactly is the *query.php* file? Is it a class or what? Looking at its code it seems to me that it is not a class. Why?

And what exactly represent `$wp_query` variable? Is it an object or what? (PHP is not typed so how can I know what a variable contains?)

What means this operation:

```
$wp_query->have_posts();
```

I think that it call another version of the `have_posts()` function (definied into the *query.php* file) that check if exist some other post to show or if they are ended.

But how exactly work? Reading the PHP OO documentation the `->` operator call a method of an object but I don't know if `$wp_query` is an object or if in this contents the `->` operator have another sense...

Can you help me to understand how exactly it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();                                     endwhile;
 else:
 _e('No blog found.', 'polymer');
endif;
?>
```

`if(have_post)` condition is to check if the page contain post, `while(have_posts)` condition if there is more than one post display in loop, `the_post()` is used to display the post `if(have_post)` condition fails it will go to `else` loop. Tell for any further doubts.....